# Twig filter return inside html tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, twig-extension

I am trying to display an Bootstrap tooltip much easier and cleaner inside twig template. I want to achieve something like this: `<i class="icon" {{'this is great tooltip'|tooltip}}></i>`
I've created twig filter:

```
class TooltipExtension extends \Twig_Extension{

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('tooltip', array($this, 'tooltipFilter',['is_safe'=>['html']])),
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('tooltip_top', array($this, 'tooltipTopFilter')),
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('tooltip_bottom', array($this, 'tooltipBottomFilter')),
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('tooltip_left', array($this, 'tooltipLeftFilter')),
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('tooltip_right', array($this, 'tooltipRightFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function tooltipFilter($title, $direction = "top")
    {
        switch($direction){
            case "top":
                return $this->tooltipTopFilter($title);

            case "bottom":
                return $this->tooltipBottomFilter($title);

            case "left":
                return $this->tooltipLeftFilter($title);

            case "right":
                return $this->tooltipRightFilter($title);

        }
    }

    public function tooltipTopFilter($title)
    {
        return ' data-toggle=tooltip data-placement=top title="'.$title.'" ';
    }

    public function tooltipBottomFilter($title)
    {
        return ' data-toggle=tooltip data-placement=bottom title='.$title.' ';
    }

    public function tooltipLeftFilter($title)
    {
        return ' data-toggle=tooltip data-placement=left title='.$title.' ';
    }

    public function tooltipRightFilter($title)
    {
        return ' data-toggle=tooltip data-placement=right title='.$title.' ';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tooltip_extension';
    }
}
```

It returns string just as I want to be. But, in html code it looks like this:

```
<i data-original-title="&quot;this" class="icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" is="" great="" tooltip&quot;=""></i>
```

As you can see, I've added `['is_safe'=>['html']]` but it doesn't changed anything at all.
I was trying to change space to hard-space but without effect.
What is worse, tooltip displays like that: [image: that tooltip is very strange] ignoring all spaces and quotation marks or apostrophes. It should looks like this: [image: this is a very good tooltip!]
Please, help me how to fix it! :)

Comment: Have you tried piping filters, adding raw filter after your tooltip filter? Something like this: `"data" | tooltip | raw`?
And, please, add part of your twig template where you call your filter...

Comment: The way i solved, when playing with your code:
`$title = html_entity_decode(str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $title));`
`return ' data-toggle=tooltip data-placement=top title='.($title)';`

Comment: `['is_safe'=>['html']]` is equal to ` |raw`
Your solution is almost great but longer texts are not wrapping because of $nbsp;. I've changed it into &thinsp; and it works great. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, but I feel that this this solution is "ugly". If you find another solution - please, leave a note here.

Comment: No problem :) Thank you again for this solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ilya Yarkovets I've found way to solve that problem. All I needed to do is to change $title by making this:

```
$title = html_entity_decode(str_replace(' ', '&thinsp;', $title));
return ' data-toggle=tooltip data-placement=top title='.($title).' ';
```

&thinsp was better than &nbsp because of text-wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [dynamic Twig filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#dynamic-filters) you can simplify the code of your extension as follows:

```
class TooltipExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('tooltip', array($this, 'tooltip',['is_safe'=>['html']])),
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('tooltip_*', array($this, 'positionedTooltip', ['is_safe'=>['html']])),
        );
    }

    public function tooltip($title)
    {    
        return $this->positionedTooltip('top', $title);
    }

    public function positionedTooltip($position, $title)
    {
        $validPositions = ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right'];
        if (!in_array($position, $validPositions)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The position of the tooltip can only be one of the following: %s', implode(', ', $validPositions)));
        }

        return sprintf(' data-toggle=tooltip data-placement=%s title="%s" ', $position, $title);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tooltip_extension';
    }
}
```

Comment: But where can I put $direction? I think that return string should looks like that:
`data-toggle=tooltip data-placement='.$direction.' title="'.$title.'" '`

Comment: You are right! I've updated the PHP code to fix some issues.

Comment: For all of the times I've extended Twig I didn't even know about dynamic filters - thanks for the heads up Javier.